# US Metro regions on google chart geo map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I want to create a geo map with a specific state region, and individual metro area regions colored by intensity of the value. I have looked at the documentation but haven't been able to achieve this. Here is an example of what I am targeting for.

[image]

Does anyone has any idea what options to use for just showing e.g., CA state, and then marking the regions by zip code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map is showing metro regions which is not the same as zip code. If you want the metro regions for California you would call `chart.draw()` with the following:

```
    var options = {
        displayMode:'regions',
        region:'US-CA',
        resolution:'metros'
    };
```

But you will need to map your data to the appropriate IDs from here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/cities-DMAregions

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5he4p5k9/1/ *[Change region to just 'US' to zoom out]*